# Unity 2D how to stop a ball which bounced by wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

i have a ball and i'm shooting it with rb2d.addForce to the mousePosition.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    _rb.AddForce(mousePos * ballSpeed);
}
```

When it hit the wall which has a **Physics2d** with bounciness, it bouncing but going forever.
How can i make the ball **stop** when it travels some amount of distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for you is probably to introduce some [drag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-drag.html) to your ball's rigidbody2d component.